# Strange symbols in IDEA terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

When I run my application from IntelliJ IDEA's terminal firstly output is normal, but after some time of program execution it starts to look like this:
[image: IDEA terminal running insane]

What my program could have done to achieve this result?

When I run it in system terminal everything is OK.

Got same results on Xubuntu and Mac machines.

Comment: There is an unresolved bug report for this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129658

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt, Thank you. Could you post it as answer because it is answer, so I could mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unresolved issue [IDEA-129658](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129658) for this exact problem. You can register on YouTrack and upvote it to improve the chances of it getting fixed sooner.